# Why my ribbon button not shows up in my form CRM 365?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-365, crm-ribbon-workbench

I add ribbon button in my entities form XrmToolBox via Ribbon Workbench plugins, I already publish my change to that form but when I refresh my page there is still no button that I already created.

My another question is how to add action to that button via plugin? I found some answer on the internet but still not 100% understand, first we create Action in our CRM so we can add it in plugin registration but what I'm still don't understand how to tell that action belongs to my ribbon button. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute Custom Action like any Workflow from Ribbon/command bar button. For that you can use Smart button in Ribbon workbench. [Read more](http://crm.fueledbysleep.com/ribbon-buttons/getting-started-with-actions/)

The plugin registration you are talking about is something what will trigger & can be used in pipeline when this Action executes. For every Custom Action - you will get a Plugin message to register against.

Assume you have an Incident, you want to quickly resolve it in single click - you can create custom action called 'Quick Resolve' which will close the incident with default resolution. Let's say on quick resolution, you want to pull all the related child incidents & close everything, then register a plugin on 'Quick Resolve' message & you can write code to pull/close all the child incidents inside plugin.

Answer (score 3):

If the new custom ribbon button has no **command** associated it will not show, other reason could be cache, try to clear it and check again.